# What is the "$\cdot$" in this: $\left\langle \nabla f,\:\cdot\right\rangle$

Tags: calculus

I've read the [Wikipedia page on exterior derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative), and it states the following:
\begin{align}
df&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i=\left\langle \nabla f,\:\color{red}{\cdot}\:\right\rangle.\tag{1}
\end{align}
I see where the $\nabla f$ comes from since, for example, if $n=4$ we would have 
\begin{align}
df&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\color{red}{dx_1}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\color{red}{dx_2}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}\color{red}{dx_3}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_4}\color{red}{dx_4}.\tag{2}
\end{align}
But now what about the $1$-forms in this summation (colored red)? Where do they come from? It looks a lot like the dot product between $\nabla f$ and some other "function" with components that are the $1$-forms $dx_1,dx_2,dx_3,dx_4$ (and indeed I have seen that the dot product can be rewritten as a summation between two vectors). Or, even more of a stretch, this reminds me of the total differential concept typically covered in multivariable calculus courses.

Why do we use the notation "$\left\langle f,\:\cdot\:\right\rangle$"? Suppose instead I wished to use the cross product or Hadamard product -- would I write them as abbreviations as "$\left\langle f,\:\times\:\right\rangle$" and "$\left\langle f,\: \odot\:\right\rangle$"? Surely there would have to be more restrictions placed upon these types of products, however.

(Note: I do not know what other tags to apply as Wikipedia states this is part of "specialized calculus" -- whatever that means)

Comment: They should have written $df(.)$.

Comment: It just stands for an arbitrary input to the function. On the left-hand side you want to feed $df$ a vector $v$. You insert $v$ where the $\color{red}{\cdot}$ is.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I see, so it isn't a marker for the dot product or cross product, my mistake. It is simply allowing an "opening" so that we may, as Ted Shifrin has said, "feed $df$ a vector $v$."

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! By the way, I'm still watching your lectures on multivariable calculus/vectors and all of that on YouTube. Very, very interesting stuff.